# jQuery infield labels plugin not working with ASP.NET project

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I'm working on a ASP.NET project and tried to use a jQuery script for infield labels but it's showing the label above the text box instead of inside it... been working on this for a few hours and haven't come up with a fix yet so I came here, my code is below, thanks for any suggestions!

Here's a link to the jQuery script I'm using: http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "LostPassword";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("LostPassword", "Account"))
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.infieldlabel.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("label").inFieldLabels();
        });
    </script>
    <fieldset>
        <table class="layout full-width key-value">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h2>Forgot your password?</h2>
<br />
<p><b>To reset your account password:</b></p> 

<p><b>1.</b> Please enter your username in the below box and click "Reset". Your username could be your E-mail address, or it may be a username you created when you set up your account.</p>
<p><b>2.</b> You will recieve an E-Mail with a link to reset your password. Follow the link and the instructions on that page to update your password.</p>
</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="position: relative">
                    <label for="UserName" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0">User Name</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("UserName")
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Reset my password" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the css of the label and or textbox (input) a look over for things like a negative margin, floats without a position attached also. Does it fade when the textbox is clicked if so that means the jQuery is 100% okay and the problem's within your css.

Comment: Okay, let me look at that and then I'll post back here if I find anything, it does fade so you're right about where the problem is.

Comment: So I tested it by cutting out all of the CSS code that affected the page and the label still shows up outside the textbox...

Comment: okay you need to add for the css td { position: relative } then the label  { position:absolute; top:0; left:0}

Comment: The example above shows tables though? or is that not how it looks any more?

Comment: I used inline styles just to be sure nothing was overwriting it. New code: <td style="{ position: relative }">
     <label for="UserName" style="{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0}">User Name</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("UserName")
    </td>

Comment: can you edit your original post to show how you have it now. I'm almost positive I know the issue is css positioning related

Comment: ahhh no you don't put in { for an inline style remove the  {} from there and check again

Comment: just adjust the top and left items within the style to get the correct position :) Glad we got there in the end :) Don't forgot to mark as answered if working :) Thanks

Comment: I selected your answer as the best and up voted your comments, wish there were more people like you on Stack overflow :)